# Fish Completions - How to prevent file completions?

Tags: autocomplete, fish

I am trying to write some completions for an in-house tool. We'll call it `thetool`.

Lots of the commands to `thetool` do not take a 'file' as an argument. I *thought* that `--no-files` and/or `--exclusive` would do this for me but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

In other words how can I write completions so that the following command does show files in the tab completion

```
$ thetool file-command *hit-tab*
```

while the following command does NOT show files in the tab completion

```
$ thetool non-file-command *hit-tab*
```

---

Let's try for a toy example:

```
$ function thetool
    echo $argv
  end
$ complete --command thetool --no-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "file-command" --description "file-command"
$ complete --command thetool --no-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "non-file-command" --description "non-file-command"
$ complete --command thetool
complete --no-files thetool -d non-file-command -a non-file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
complete --no-files thetool -d file-command -a file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
```

now try the completions out:

```
$ thetool *hit-tab*
file-command  (file-command)  non-file-command  (non-file-command)
```

Looks good so far...

```
$ thetool non-file-command *hit-tab*
bin/                  dev.yml       Judgment.lock  README.md              TODO.md           
completion_test.fish  exe/          lib/           shipit.production.yml  vendor/           
completion_test.zsh   Gemfile       linters/       sorbet/                zsh_completions.sh
coverage/             Gemfile.lock  Rakefile       test/
```

SEE! What are all those file suggestions doing there?!

Let's try again:

```
$ complete --command thetool --force-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "file-command" --erase
$ complete --command thetool --force-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "file-command"
$ complete --command thetool --no-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "non-file-command"
$ complete --command thetool
complete --no-files thetool -a non-file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
complete --force-files thetool -a file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
$ thetool *hit-tab*
bin/                  dev.yml       Gemfile.lock   non-file-command       sorbet/  zsh_completions.sh
completion_test.fish  exe/          Judgment.lock  Rakefile               test/    
completion_test.zsh   file-command  lib/           README.md              TODO.md  
coverage/             Gemfile       linters/       shipit.production.yml  vendor/
```

arrrg can someone help me understand what is going on and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no call that ever tells fish to disable files if it has seen `non-file-command`.

Let's go through them:

```
complete --command thetool --no-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "file-command" --description "file-command"
```

fish *has* seen `non-file-command`, the condition is false.

```
complete --command thetool --no-files --condition "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command" --arguments "non-file-command" --description "non-file-command"
```

fish *has* seen `non-file-command`, the condition is false.

```
complete --command thetool
```

This does nothing.

```
complete --no-files thetool -d non-file-command -a non-file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
```

fish *has* seen `non-file-command`, the condition is false.

```
complete --no-files thetool -d file-command -a file-command -n 'not __fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command non-file-command'
```

fish *has* seen `non-file-command`, the condition is false.

No condition where we'd disable files is true, so we default to enabling them. There is nothing that tells it to disable files if `non-file-command` was given.

Add

```
complete --command thetool --no-files --condition " __fish_seen_subcommand_from non-file-command"
```

and it'll work.

Or, if you have a lot of things that *don't* take files and just a few that do, you can add

```
complete --command thetool --no-files
```

which will disable files *always* (it has no condition so it's always true, as long as you're completing `thetool`), and then force-files for those cases that do, e.g.

```
complete --command thetool --condition "__fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command" --force-files
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this might sort me out. I'll report back after I've given this a try in the use cases for my completion use-case.

Comment: This seems to have been the piece I was missing. I think I understand now though. As you say, I needed to give it the condition for which to apply the `--no-files` or `--force-files`

My command doesn't have a lot of commands that take files, and so I've chosen the second route you proposed which turns on `--no-files` by default for everything under `thetool` and in specific cases where I know I need files I've used `--force-files` with a specific `--condition "__fish_seen_subcommand_from file-command"`.

Comment: A related question that we should maybe sneak in here - is there a way to tell `fish`s built-in file completion to only allow certain files by checking their extension?

Comment: No. Extension checking in general is fraught with problems, and useful much less than you think. So you'll have to write your own if it's really what you want. A few globs here and there would get you most of the way.